The apple-app-site-association file not found
We're trying to set up an association file for a website that didn't have it before.
We've uploaded the file to https://www.our-website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association (as suggested in the documentation). Unfortunately, it didn't work, the links still open in the browser instead of our app and we can't seem to figure out why.
We tried querying the Apple CDN, and for some reason it returns 404:
$ curl -v https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/www.our-website.com
>
< HTTP/2 404
< apple-failure-details: {"cause":"invalid character '\u003c' looking for beginning of value"}
< apple-failure-reason: SWCERR00401 Bad JSON content
< apple-from: https://www.our-website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
< apple-try-direct: false
< cache-control: max-age=3600,public
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< via: https/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pst-001.ts.apple.com (acdn/153.14426), http/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pac-001.ts.apple.com (acdn/153.14426), https/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pfe-002.ts.apple.com (acdn/153.14426), 1.1 varnish
< cdnuuid: 1741f0c3-efb3-42fa-b574-ae3bfebb13f6-333001418
< expires: Fri, 24 May 2024 10:43:27 GMT
< accept-ranges: bytes
< age: 1693
< date: Fri, 24 May 2024 11:11:25 GMT
< x-cdn: fsly
< x-served-by: cache-bma1670-BMA
< x-cache: hit-stale, hit-fresh, hit-stale, HIT
< x-cache-hits: 0
< x-timer: S1716549085.460891,VS0,VE1
< content-length: 10
<
Not Found

Requesting the association file directly returns 200 though (we tried from different networks, all works fine):
$ https://www.our-website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Fri, 24 May 2024 11:03:15 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 200
< cache-control: no-store
< x-varnish-director: sports_web_pro
< vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< x-cache: MISS
< x-age: 0
< age: 0
< accept-ranges: bytes
<
(json content here)

According to AASA validator, all is good:

It's been several days already, so hopefully this isn't a caching issue. Previously we also tried hosting the file at https://www.our-website.com/apple-app-site-association but the result was the same.
Strangely, the diagnostic tool on iPhone (in Settings > Developer) reports that all is A-OK:

This is all thoroughly confusing, especially the failure message: {"cause":"invalid character '\u003c' looking for beginning of value"}. Is the CDN bot trying to parse the body even after receiving 404? Or is this the cached HTML that was returned at .well-known when we were trying to host the file at the root? (since '\u003c' is the opening angle bracket).
Anyone has any ideas?

UPDATE: TN3155 suggests running sudo swcutil dl -d www.our-website.com:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (SWCErrorDomain error 7.)

I have no clue what this error means but I'm finding references to the same cause, invalid character '\u003c' looking for beginning of value.

UPDATE 2: I haven't posted the content of the file (since I didn't think it was the cause of the issue), but here goes:
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www"
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www"
        ]
    }
}

The file is quite simple. I have confirmed that it works in the developer mode (when I add applinks:www.our-website.com?mode=developer to the list of associated domains). We also tried deploying hosting this file to the staging server (at stage-www.our-website.com, has pretty much the same configuration as the production server) and https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/stage-www.our-website.com returns 200, so this must be an issue with the CDN.

"We've uploaded the file to https://www.our-website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association" Well, that isn't the only thing you have to do in order to prepare your app for universal links. You also have to give your app a domain entitlement. Did you do that? If so, why doesn't your question cite it? Plus, do you understand how to bypass the caching in order to test your universal links during development?

@matt yes, the domain entitlement has been set up. The configuration was copied from another target in the project so I didn't expect any issues there, but you're right, I should have mentioned this in the question. I'm also aware of the development mode, if there was a problem with the content of the association file it would probably help find it, but in this case the problem is that the CDN bot can't find the file (unless, of course, the 404 error is a red herring).

Could you show (in the question) the content of the site association file? I've always followed https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10098 to the letter and it has always worked.

I'll be away from my computer for a week or so, I'll update the question when I'm back.

@matt I have updated the question with the content of the association file (sorry for the delay). Even though the file uses the legacy format, it works fine in the developer mode and when deployed to the staging server which makes me think this is a CDN issue. We'll try to delete and redeploy the file and maybe convert it to the new syntax if that doesn't help, otherwise we'll have to file a request with the developer support (once they're back to handling private support requests after WWDC).

Citing from the docs "Apple’s content delivery network requests the apple-app-site-association file for your domain within 24 hours. Devices check for updates approximately once per week after app installation."

@derpirscher I wish it were that simple as just waiting for a while, but it's been weeks at this point.

We have found the culprit: the server hosting the association file was wrapping the content of the file in HTML if user agent contained the word "bot" (and returning proper JSON for web browsers and curl). And of course the CDN bot makes the request with User-Agent: AASA-Bot/*:
curl -A "AASA-Bot/*" https://www.our-website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
<html><head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www"
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDE12345.com.our-website.www"
        ]
    }
}</pre></body></html>

And that's where the opening angle bracket the bot was complaining about came from.
Once the offending piece of logic was updated, everything worked as expected.

I would try the following diagnostic checks:

Double-check your JSON format and make sure it's served with the application/json MIME type.
Ensure there's no Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the file.
If the CDN's got a wrong version cached, you might need to reach out to Apple to clear it. Or maybe try deploying to another server? (Silly option?)
Verify you're not accidentally serving HTML – the CDN's error suggests it might be looking at an HTML page.

Try also the following:
Setting your cache control header to Cache-Control: public, max-age=0.
Goodluck!
